# No me aparecen los campos input con v-model

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Estoy practicando con `Laravel` y `Vue.js`, realizando actividades y viendo muchos videos en Youtube. Hoy me encontré con un problema que no sé cómo solucionar:

Tengo un formulario para agregar tareas:

```
<form @submit.prevent="agregar">
    <!--<label>Nombre:</label>-->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control mb-2" >
    <!--<label>Descripción:</label>-->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Descripción" class="form-control mb-2" >
    <!--botones del formulario-->
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Agregar</button>
</form>
```

En esta forma como está el código me funciona correctamente el formulario, me muestra los dos `inputs` con el botón `Agregar`.

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero ahora viene el problema, cuando le agrego el `v-model` al input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control mb-2" v-model="tarea.nombre">`
```

me desaparecen todos los campos. No hay error de código porque revisé todo y no sé cuál puede ser el inconveniente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Tienes creados esos datos que le quieres asignar al modelo del `input` dentro de tu instancia `Vue`?

Para añadir un `v-model` al input con `tarea.nombre` [debes tener esas propiedades creadas](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) en el objeto `data`. Observa el siguiente snippet para que notes que funciona usando tu mismo patrón de código:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tarea: {
      nombre: ""
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" v-model="tarea.nombre" />
    El nombre es: {{ tarea.nombre }}
  </form>
</div>
```

Nota: Hace un tiempo atrás creé [un pequeño tutorial de introducción a Vue.js](https://xprimiendo.com/vue-js-tutorial-iniciacion-10-minutos/). Aunque es muy básico, no está mal para empezar y relacionarte con este *framework*.